# non-aggregate min() with NULLs

Tags: sqlite, null

I am using the [the multi-argument form of `min`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#minoreunc) but some values are `NULL`.

For example:

```
SELECT min(1,2,NULL);
```

How do I update this query to ignore `NULL`s and return the desired value `1`?

Comment: Perhaps change to `select min(F) from (select 1 F union select 2 union select null) where F is not null`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ifnull()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) to introduce some special value that can be compared:

```
SELECT min(ifnull(1,    -123),
           ifnull(2,    -123),
           ifnull(NULL, -123));
```

If you want to get NULL if all parameters are NULL, you have to apply [`nullif()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#nullif) to the result.